# Image not showing in IE but is showing in Mozilla - Odd

Tags: graphics, internet-explorer-8, mozilla

If you look at this link: http://www.internetworld.co.uk/g/2010/ExhibLogos/ExhibID_137_Graphic1.jpg.

In IE8, it doesn't show. In Mozilla it does. I have no idea as to what would cause this issue as this is just a bog standard jpg. This is also happening for other companies other than ourselves on the same site. Can anyone shed any light on it for me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it a CMYK JPEG? IE still can't read them. Convert it to RGB and all should be well in the world.

Comment: Thanks very much. This sorted it.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, but your colorspace is likely something that is not supported by IE 8.

Hope this helps...